# Saving and loading a list in a file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently preparing for an exam and am working on the following task:

How can I pass an ArrayList to a "save" method that stores the list's data and another "load" method that passes the data back?

```
class Person {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String sortname;

public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        updateSortname();
```

//getter and setter..

According to the task I should use these methods:

```
public static List<Person> load(String filename) throws IOException {
        return ??;
}


public static Person load(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        return ??;
}


public static void save(String filename, List<Person> list) throws IOException {
}


public static void save(DataOutputStream out, Person person) throws IOException {
}


public static List<Person> unserialize(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return ??;
}


public static void serialize(String filename, List<Person> persons) throws IOException {
}
```

This is the main method that should produce the following output:

> [Willy Wonka (WonkaWilly), Charlie Bucket (BucketCharlie), Grandpa Joe
>   (JoeGrandpa)]
>
> [Willy Wonka (WonkaWilly), Charlie Bucket (BucketCharlie), Grandpa Joe
>   (JoeGrandpa)]
>
> [Willy Wonka (WonkaWilly), Charlie Bucket (BucketCharlie), Grandpa Joe
>   (JoeGrandpa)]

```
public class PersonTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Willy", "Wonka"));
    persons.add(new Person("Charlie", "Bucket"));
    persons.add(new Person("Grandpa", "Joe"));
    System.out.println(persons);

    Person.save("persons.sav", persons);
    persons = Person.load("persons.sav");
    System.out.println(persons);
    Person.serialize("persons.ser", persons);
    persons = Person.unserialize("persons.ser");
    System.out.println(persons);
}
```

}

It should look something like this. But I don't know how I do it for ArrayLists.

```
public static void save(String filename , Graph graph ) throws IOException{

try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (filename)))) {
out.writeObject (graph);
}
}

public static Graph load (String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

Graph graph = null;
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (new BufferedInputStream ( new FileInputStream (filename)))) {
graph = (Graph) in.readObject();
}
return graph;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need output of the `Person` Object to be as, we need to override `toString()` of `Person` class.

> [Willy Wonka (WonkaWilly), Charlie Bucket (BucketCharlie), Grandpa Joe (JoeGrandpa)]

```
class Person {

//Respective Constructor, Getter & Setter methods


/* Returns the string representation of Person Class. 
 * The format of string is firstName lastName (lastNameFirstName)*/

  @Override
  public String toString() { 
    return String.format(firstName + " " + lastName + "("+ lastName + firstName + ")"); 
  } 
}
```

There are many approaches to writing objects to file. Here is with `PrintWriter`

Save Objects to File

```
public static void save(String filename, List<Person> list) throws IOException {
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
 for (Person person : list) {
    pw.println(person.toString());
   }
 pw.close();
}
```

**Or Use serialization**

// You could use serialization mechanism.
To use it, you need to do the following:

1. Declare the `Person` class as implementing `Serializable`:

   ```
   public class Person implements Serializable {
       ...
     @Override
     public String toString() { 
        return String.format(firstName + " " + lastName + "("+ lastName + firstName + ")"); 
     } 
   }
   ```
2. Write your list to file:

   ```
   public static void save(String filename, List<Person> list) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(list);
    oos.close();
   }
   ```
3. Read List from File:

   ```
   public static List<Person> load(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    List<Person> list = (List<Person>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return list;
   }
   ```

Comment: The way with serialization is very good and works. Thanks for this suggestion my friend. I am now trying to create the third output using this hint.

Comment: With your method, the third edition also worked. Thank you very much. Now I have to try to understand it

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void save(String filename , ArrayList<Person> persons) throws IOException{

    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (filename)))) {
        for(int i = 0; i < persons.size; i++){
               out.writeObject(persons.get(i));
        }   
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have solved it now with the serialization, as Vikalp has suggested